# HomeBrew cannot install anything

Tags: homebrew

I try to install HomeBrew but when I try it, it stops after update. When I close this with ctrl + c then it looks like HomeBrew was installed but when I try to install some app the again stop after update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that issue by reinstalling HomeBrew.